# WLS 12.1.3 - cannot read property file while uploading EAR. ECLIPSE "Run as" deployement works

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic12c

when i deploy EAR using WLS Console (upload from file) application cannot read configuration file (xml).

When deploying using RUN AS - Run On Server option there is no problem. App works fine.

That's how I get configuration files:

```
File confFile =  new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/fop_kf.xml").getFile());
    log.info("confFile pobrany.");
File xsltfile =  new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/fak_db_gsk.xsl").getFile());
    log.info("xsltFile pobrany.");
```

log:

```
getInvoicePdf - IOException java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u01/domains/dev1/servers/MngSrv1/tmp/_WL_user/gskdb-EA/eo14hh/gskdb-EJB.jar!/META-INF/fop_kf.xml (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) at org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser.<init>(FopConfParser.java:141) at org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser.<init>(FopConfParser.java:114) at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:132) at
```

my files are in META-INF folder

When I check whether files are on server - files exists in deployed jar.

thanks for help !